# Enterpise Manager 12c to Database 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle-12c

Does Oracle Enterpise Manager 12c can be install with Oracle Database 11g? Because the Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. We are currently using it on a 11g RAC database.

Do you need any other details?